# Pivot table, Excel Online, show all months in time period as columns even if values are empty? (recreating Query from Google Sheets)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a query formula and I'm trying to recreate this in Excel. I thought Power Query would be the right place, but it doesn't seem to be available in 365 online.

I tried building a pivot table and got some what close, but it's missing months that have no data.

This is my Google Sheets formula

```
where F != 0 
group by E 
order by sum(F) desc
label sum(F) ''",0)
```

The formula spits out something like this: [image]
(I included the headers in my screenshot, but they are not part of the query formula)

In my pivot table, this is the output

[image]

I have a helper table of all the months in the time period selected (they're dynamic based on the starting month the user selects), but I don't see a way of referencing that in my sheet.

Before I go buy a subscription to get the desktop version of Excel to work with Power Query, is there something I can do here to get the pivot table to do what I want?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach... see if this is what you are looking for:

Assume you are given data set like this:

[image]

Formula:

```
=LAMBDA(RANGE,
 LAMBDA(REVENUE,DATE,VALUE,
  LAMBDA(UREVENUE,UDATE,VALUE,
   LAMBDA(PIVOT,
    HSTACK(
     VSTACK("REVENUE",UREVENUE),
     BYROW(PIVOT,LAMBDA(ROW,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDEX(ROW,1))),"TOTAL",SUM(ROW)))),
     PIVOT
    )
   )(
    MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(UREVENUE)+1,COUNTA(UDATE),LAMBDA(ROW,COL,
     IFS(
      ROW=1,INDEX(UDATE,COL),
      TRUE,SUM(FILTER(VALUE,(REVENUE=INDEX(UREVENUE,ROW-1))*(DATE=INDEX(UDATE,COL)),0))
     )
    ))
   )
  )(UNIQUE(REVENUE),UNIQUE(DATE),IF(VALUE="",0,VALUE))
 )(INDEX(RANGE,,1),INDEX(RANGE,,2),INDEX(RANGE,,3))
)($A$2:$C$19)
```

This formula mainly uses `MAKEARRAY()` with `INDEX()` to recreate the output of google `QUERY()`.

1. name `$A$2:$C$19` as `RANGE` with `LAMBDA()`,
2. name `Col1,Col2,Col3` of `RANGE` as `REVENUE,DATE,VALUE` with `LAMBDA()`,
3. get unique values of `REVENUE` and `DATE` with `UNIQUE()`,
4. fill in `0` for empty values in `VALUE` with `IF()`,
5. name the unique values as `UREVENUE` and `UDATE`, and update the values of `VALUE` with `LAMBDA()`,
6. get pivot sum of `REVENUE` and `DATE` with `MAKEARRAY()`, which `COUNTA(UREVENUE)+1` as number of `ROW`, and `COUNTA(UDATE)` as number of `COL`,
7. the reason why we need to `+1` in `ROW` count, is because that we have to add a header row for the pivoted data,
8. inside `MAKEARRAY()`, fill in every `CELL` with `IFS()` according to some conditions,
9. when `ROW` index is `1`, it should be the header row, so return the value of `UDATE` as header, `INDEX()` here determines which value of `UDATE` should be shown according to the `COL` index,
10. when `ROW` index is not `1`, `FILTER()` the data of `VALUE` according to `UREVENUE` and `UDATE`, same as step 9, we use `INDEX()` to determines which value of the given data sets are we referencing, `SUM()` the result of `FILTER()` to form a single value for each `CELL`,
11. name the result of `MAKEARRAY()` as `PIVOT` with `LAMBDA()`,
12. get `SUM()` of each `ROW` in `PIVOT` with `BYROW()`,
13. stack the outputs with `VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` to form the result.

---

Just noticed that you have mentioned about there is another table to select the data you would like to display according to months, so I updated the formula, and also separated the header part from `MAKEARRAY()` so the whole thing may hopefully looks logically easier to understand:

[image: image2]

```
=LAMBDA(DATARANGE,SELECTED,HEADERS,
 LAMBDA(REVENUE,DATE,VALUE,SELECTED,
  LAMBDA(UREVENUE,VALUE,
   LAMBDA(PIVOT,HEADERS,
    LAMBDA(TOTAL,
     VSTACK(HEADERS,HSTACK(UREVENUE,TOTAL,PIVOT))
    )(BYROW(PIVOT,LAMBDA(ROW,SUM(ROW))))
   )(
    MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(UREVENUE),COUNTA(SELECTED),LAMBDA(ROW,COL,
     SUM(FILTER(VALUE,(REVENUE=INDEX(UREVENUE,ROW))*(DATE=INDEX(SELECTED,COL)),0))
    )),
    HSTACK(HEADERS,TRANSPOSE(SELECTED))
   )
  )(UNIQUE(REVENUE),IF(VALUE="",0,VALUE))
 )(INDEX(DATARANGE,,1),INDEX(DATARANGE,,2),INDEX(DATARANGE,,3),TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(SELECTED,,",")))
)($A$2:$C$19,$F$1,HSTACK("REVENUE","TOTAL"))
```

1. name `$A$2:$C$19` as `DATARANGE`, `$F$1` as `SELECTED`, `HSTACK("REVENUE","TOTAL")` as `HEADERS` with `LAMBDA()`, which the two texts inside `HEADERS` would be the titles of output column 1 and 2,
2. name `Col1,Col2,Col3` of `DATARANGE` as `REVENUE,DATE,VALUE`, and `TEXTSPLIT()` `SELECTED` into an `ARRAY`, apply `TRIM()` on the `ARRAY` to get rid of extra spacing if there is any, and update it as values of `SELECTED` with `LAMBDA()`,
3. get unique values of `REVENUE` with `UNIQUE()`, and fill in `0` for empty values in `VALUE` with `IF()`,
4. name the unique values as `UREVENUE`, and update the values of `VALUE` with `LAMBDA()`,
5. update values of `HEADERS`, `HSTACK()` it with `TRANSPOSE(SELECTED)` to form the complete `HEADERS`,
6. get pivot sum of `REVENUE` and `DATE` with `MAKEARRAY()`, which `COUNTA(UREVENUE)` as number of `ROW`, and `COUNTA(SELECTED)` as number of `COL`,
7. inside `MAKEARRAY()`, fill in every `CELL` with `FILTER()`, filter the data of `VALUE` according to `UREVENUE` and `SELECTED`, uses `INDEX()` to determines which value of the given data are we referencing as criteria, `SUM()` the result of `FILTER()` to form a single value for each `CELL`, name the result of `MAKEARRAY()` as `PIVOT` with `LAMBDA()`,
8. get `SUM()` of each `ROW` in `PIVOT` with `BYROW()`, name the result of `BYROW()` as `TOTAL` with `LAMBDA()`,
9. stack the outputs with `VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` to form the final result.

---

Some `SORT()` is added to help rearrange the output data if needed, controlled by the value of `SORTREVENUE`,`SORTTOTAL`,`SORTPIVOT`.

In the 1st `LAMBDA()`, pass `ASC` or `DESC` to activate related `SORT()`, or leave it blank to turn that `SORT()` off.

Be noticed, sort result of `SORTTOTAL` will overwrite sort result of `SORTREVENUE`.

```
=LAMBDA(DATARANGE,SELECTED,HEADERS,SORTREVENUE,SORTTOTAL,SORTPIVOT,
 LAMBDA(REVENUE,DATE,VALUE,SELECTED,MONTHS,
  LAMBDA(UREVENUE,SELECTED,
   LAMBDA(PIVOT,HEADERS,
    LAMBDA(TOTAL,
     VSTACK(
      HEADERS,
      LAMBDA(OUTPUT,ASC,DESC,
       IF(OR(ASC,DESC),SORT(OUTPUT,2,IF(DESC,-1,ASC)),OUTPUT)
      )(HSTACK(UREVENUE,TOTAL,PIVOT),SORTTOTAL="ASC",SORTTOTAL="DESC")
     )
    )(BYROW(PIVOT,LAMBDA(ROW,SUM(ROW))))
   )(
    MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(UREVENUE),COUNTA(SELECTED),LAMBDA(ROW,COL,
     SUM(FILTER(VALUE,(REVENUE=INDEX(UREVENUE,ROW))*(DATE=INDEX(SELECTED,COL)),0))
    )),
    HSTACK(HEADERS,TRANSPOSE(SELECTED))
   )
  )(
   LAMBDA(REVENUE,ASC,DESC,
    IF(OR(ASC,DESC),SORT(REVENUE,,IF(DESC,-1,ASC)),REVENUE)
   )(UNIQUE(REVENUE),SORTREVENUE="ASC",SORTREVENUE="DESC"),
   LAMBDA(TEXT,NUM,ASC,DESC,
    IF(OR(ASC,DESC),
     XLOOKUP(SORT(XLOOKUP(SELECTED,TEXT,NUM),,IF(DESC,-1,ASC)),NUM,TEXT),
     SELECTED
    )
   )(INDEX(MONTHS,,1),INDEX(MONTHS,,2),SORTPIVOT="ASC",SORTPIVOT="DESC")
  )
 )(
  INDEX(DATARANGE,,1),
  INDEX(DATARANGE,,2),
  INDEX(DATARANGE,,3),
  TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(UPPER($F$1),,",")),
  HSTACK({"JAN";"FEB";"MAR";"APR";"MAY";"JUN";"JUL";"AUG";"SEP";"OCT";"NOV";"DEC"},SEQUENCE(12))
 )
)($A$2:$C$19,$F$1,HSTACK("REVENUE","TOTAL"),"DESC","DESC","DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this might work. I'm going to try this out tomorrow morning and report back